# How are MS and MA programs in Mathematics different?

Tags: graduate-school, mathematics, masters, job-search

Most graduate programs in Math only offer a PhD program, but some provide either an MS or MA in Math. Are there any significant differences I should be aware of between the two, or are they practically identical?

Does an MS provide better preparation for PhD while an MA provides a better teaching experience? Does it depend on the university and course requirements?

Also, is there a general perception from academic or industry employers on one being better than the other?

Comment: This likely varies a lot from one institution to another, but at the institution where I earned my bachelors and masters degrees, the difference between a BA and BS, (and the difference between an MA and an MS) came down to whether or not you took a foreign language.  If you had sufficient foreign language hours, you could get a BA/MA.  Otherwise, you took CS classes, and got a BS/MS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might not be any difference at all. My masters is an MA from an R1 university. I had the choice of degrees just by applying for one or the other. There was no difference in requirements. I took the MA since my math undergraduate was a BA, and again, I had the choice, but only there because I'd taken various humanities courses as well as math.

It might also just be up to the university what to call the degree and how the university is organized. In many, maybe most, US universities, the math department is in the Liberal Arts division or school. So MA might be more common there, where if it is part of the Engineering school an MS would be more natural.

It might also be reasonable to make a distinction for pure math (MA, perhaps) and applied math (MS). Applied math can depend on use of the scientific method as found in science, where pure math seldom does.

But, the requirements are likely to be very similar, if not identical. No one ever blinked at the titles of my degrees: BA, MA, PhD.

Some schools might differ from this of course and want some way to distinguish between a degree with thesis and one without. But you can still be a success with either option.

---

But note, also, that "most graduate programs in Math only offer a PhD program" is probably incorrect. Some_ might not accept students for *only* a masters (US perspective), but doctoral students may still be able earn a masters along the way, sometimes just by asking, sometimes by writing a separate thesis (my personal case), and sometimes as a consolation prize for those who drop out.

Of course in those places that require a masters for entry into a doctoral program, that might be the only option.

Comment: Indeed, seems mostly a university-specific thing. Princeton's CS department offers both an AB and BSE degree in computer science. As it says on their FAQ page, "Should I choose one degree over the other depending on what I want to do after graduation?
Our experience is that employers and graduate schools do not care whether you're an AB or a BSE (and most don't understand the distinction)."

Comment: At least one university I'm familiar with, secondary teachers got MAs in math, and the rest MSes.

Comment: I believe that at my university, the general education requirements are different between BS and BA degrees. BS degrees have to have a certain number of "hard sciences" classes (physics, chemistry, biology) whereas that number is smaller for a BA where instead the number of social sciences credit hours is larger.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, as it was at mine. I'd just fulfilled requirements for both so got to choose either.